# Play Youtube video in background using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, youtube

I have been successfully using YouTubePlayerSupportFragment to play YouTube videos.

But I still need to continue playing in the background, when the back button is pressed.

If you have any ideas, please share with me. Thanks!

Here is my code -

---

YoutubePlayerFragment class

```
public class YoutubePlayerFragment {
public static String DEVELOPER_KEY = "DEVELOPER_KEY";
public static boolean isFullScreen;

public static void setYoutubePlayerFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    MainFragment.youtubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    MainFragment.youtubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, new OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
                boolean paramBoolean) {
            PlayerService.youTubePlayer = player;
            PlayerService.youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            setListener(fragment.getActivity());
        }
    });
    replaceFragment(fragment);
}

public static void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment == null)
        return;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = fragment.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtubeplayerFrameLayout,
            MainFragment.youtubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public static void setListener(final Activity activity) {
    PlayerService.youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(new OnFullscreenListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullScreen) {
            YoutubePlayerFragment.isFullScreen = isFullScreen;
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setOnFullscreenListener : onFullscreen");
        }
    });

    PlayerService.youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onAdStarted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onError : " + arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onLoaded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onLoading");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onVideoEnded");
        }

        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlayerStateChangeListener : onVideoStarted");
        }
    });

    PlayerService.youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new PlaybackEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlaybackEventListener : onBuffering");
            if (MainActivity.isBack && PlayerService.youTubePlayer != null) {
                PlayerService.youTubePlayer.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlaybackEventListener : onPaused");
            PlayerFrameLayout.ibPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_36dp);
            if (MainActivity.isBack && PlayerService.youTubePlayer != null) {
                PlayerService.youTubePlayer.play();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlaybackEventListener : onPlaying");
            PlayerFrameLayout.ibPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_white_36dp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlaybackEventListener : onSeekTo");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            Log.d(App.tagName, "setPlaybackEventListener : onStopped");             
        }
    });
}}
```

Using Service to play Youtube video.

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {
public static YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer = null;
private int MSG;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(App.tagName, "PlayerService : onCreate");
    YoutubePlayerFragment.setYoutubePlayerFragment(MainFragment.mainFragment);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.d(App.tagName, "PlayerService : onStartCommand");
    MediaInfo mediaInfo = MusicListFragment.getCurrentMp3Info();
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(mediaInfo.video_id);
    youTubePlayer.play();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}   }
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to play video on background using YouTubePlayerFragment... I've been working with YouTube API and it'll stop playing even when some other view would overlay any part of video, so I guess it's not possible
It's sad that WebView seems to be more suitable for playing YouTube videos than YouTubePlayerFragment...

Comment: Thanks!  It's sad...I will try to use webview to play youtube in background...

Comment: Can't use webview to play youtube, because it show the error message "This video contains content from WMG...". How to solve it?

Comment: It's a video copyright issue... it happens when author of that video doesn't allow his video to be played in embedded player. If you've managed to play that video through YouTubePlayerFragment, that would be probably only way for you...

Comment: You can use floating window feature as described here: http://www.labnol.org/internet/background-youtube-android/27046/.
Or maybe if you would be able to get audio track from that video, you could continue playing that audio on the background in MediaPlayer... apparently, it's possible to do that: http://lifehacker.com/ulisten-plays-just-youtube-audio-in-the-background-whil-1452024153

Comment: Thanks for your comments,
I will try to use a floating window function or get audio tracks from video.